# FOSCKEditorBundle genera el editor bien cuando llamo a formulario vía AJAX, pero en un formulario que se carga sin AJAX, no funciona

Tags: jquery, symfony, ckeditor, symfony5

En mi aplicación Symfony 5.4 tengo varios formularios que se cargan vía AJAX, y los cuales contienen editores WYSIWYG con CKEditorBundle que funcionan correctamente. En un formulario específico que no es cargado vía AJAX, el CKEditor que contiene no se ejecuta.

Esta es la configuración del CKEditor:

```
#fos_ckeditor.yaml    
twig:
    form_themes:
        - '@FOSCKEditor/Form/ckeditor_widget.html.twig'
fos_ck_editor:
    base_path: 'bundles/fosckeditor/'
    js_path:   'bundles/fosckeditor/ckeditor.js'
    jquery_path: 'bundles/fosckeditor/adapters/jquery.js'
    jquery: true
    #autoload: false
    input_sync: true
    default_config: 'minima_config'
    configs:
        minima_config:
            language: '%kernel.default_locale%'
            font_defaultLabel: 'Arial'
            fontSize_defaultLabel: '12px'
            uiColor: '#f9f9f9'
            async: true
            autoload: true
            toolbar: 'minima_toolbar'
        media_config:
            language: '%kernel.default_locale%'
            uiColor: '#f9f9f9'
            async: true
            autoload: true
            toolbar: 'media_toolbar'
    toolbars:
        configs:
            minima_toolbar: [[Bold, Italic, Underline, Strike, Subscript, Superscript], [NumberedList, BulletedList, '-', Outdent, Indent, '-', JustifyLeft, JustifyCenter, JustifyRight, JustifyBlock], [Maximize]]
            media_toolbar: [[Bold, Italic, Underline, Strike, Subscript, Superscript], [TextColor], [NumberedList, BulletedList, '-', Outdent, Indent, '-', JustifyLeft, JustifyCenter, JustifyRight, JustifyBlock],[Preview, Print], [Styles, Format, Font, FontSize], [Maximize]]
```

Simplemente en el formulario hago:

```
->add('mensaje', CKEditorType::class, [
     'label' => false                        
])
```

La vista del formulario nada diferente, solo declarar los widgets.

La consola del navegador me muestra el siguiente error:

```
Uncaught Error: jQuery should be loaded before CKEditor jQuery adapter.
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    <anonymous> https://dominioapp.dev/buzon-interno/redactar/nuevo/mensaje:406
```

Lo que entiendo es lo siguiente: al cargarse un formulario vía AJAX, y teniendo en cuenta la configuración de CKEditor (con `autoload:true`), ya la librería JQuery está cargada previamente en la vista, y ckeditor.js se ejecuta correctamente, pero en este formulario en específico que no es cargado vía AJAX, en el layout que se le asocia a la vista (del formulario) se está cargando `JQuery` despúes de `CKEditor`. ***Cómo logro establecer el orden de carga de CKEditor si fuera el caso????***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución encontrada consiste en deshabilitar en la configuración del CKEditorBundle el autoload y el async, y en la vista del formulario cargar "manualmente" las librerías del ckeditor.

```
#fos_ckeditor.yaml:
fos_ck_editor:
    base_path: 'bundles/fosckeditor/'
    js_path:   'bundles/fosckeditor/ckeditor.js'
    jquery_path: 'bundles/fosckeditor/adapters/jquery.js'
    jquery: true
    #autoload: false
    input_sync: true
    default_config: 'minima_config'
    configs:
        minima_config:
            language: '%kernel.default_locale%'
            font_defaultLabel: 'Arial'
            fontSize_defaultLabel: '12px'
            uiColor: '#f9f9f9'
            async: true
            autoload: true
            toolbar: 'minima_toolbar'            
        buzonInternoMensaje_config:
            language: '%kernel.default_locale%'
            uiColor: '#f9f9f9'
            async: false
            autoload: false
            toolbar: 'buzonInternoMensaje_toolbar'
    toolbars:
        configs:
            minima_toolbar: [[Bold, Italic, Underline, Strike, Subscript, Superscript], [NumberedList, BulletedList, '-', Outdent, Indent, '-', JustifyLeft, JustifyCenter, JustifyRight, JustifyBlock], [Maximize]]                
            buzonInternoMensaje_toolbar: [[Bold, Italic, Underline, Strike, Subscript, Superscript], [TextColor], [NumberedList, BulletedList, '-', Outdent, Indent, '-', JustifyLeft, JustifyCenter, JustifyRight, JustifyBlock],[Preview, Print], [Styles, Format, Font, FontSize], [Maximize]]
```

En la clase del del formulario se emplea la configuración `buzonInternoMensaje_config`:

```
 ->add('mensaje', CKEditorType::class, [
                    'label' => false,
                    'config' => ['config_name' => 'buzonInternoMensaje_config'],
                    'attr' => ['class' => 'hidden'],
                    'constraints' => [new NotBlank(['message' => 'El cuerpo del mensaje es obligatorio'])]
                ])
```

Por último en la vista del formulario, se carga el ckeditor.js y el adapter.js, teniendo en cuenta que la librería JQuery se carga desde el layout asociado, y se inicializa el CKEditor sobre el elemento con id `buzon_interno_mensaje_mensaje`

```
{% block javascripts %}
    {{ parent() }}
    <script src="{{ asset('bundles/fosckeditor/ckeditor.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('bundles/fosckeditor/adapters/jquery.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            CKEDITOR.replace('buzon_interno_mensaje_mensaje');
            setTimeout(function () {
                $('#buzon_interno_mensaje_mensaje').toggleClass('hidden');
            }, 1000);
            $('#btnRedactarMensaje').toggleClass('disabled');
        });
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```